# How to handle List IndexOutOfBoundsException?

Tags: java, list, linked-list, indexoutofboundsexception

I am trying to write a get() method for a LinkedList, where the private method is used by the public one, but I keep getting an IndexOutOfBoundsException and I don't know where it's coming from.

The exception also only seems to not like integer values, strings, doubles, and all other data types are ok.

The list has no set length in main so right now I don't know why java is complaining.

```
public E get(int i)
   {
      if (i < 0 || i >= size())
      {
         throw new IndexOutOfBoundsException("" + i);
      }
      else if (i == 0 )
      {
         return head.value;
      }
      return get(i, head);
   }

   private E get(int i, Node node)
   {
      if (i == 0)
      {
         return (E) node.value;
      }
      return (E) get(i - 1, node.next);
   }
```

Comment: what does `size()` return?

Comment: The stack trace *tells* you where it's coming from.

Comment: Why the type cast `(E)`?

Comment: If the exception is throw by the code you've shown us, odds are that `size()` doesn't return the correct value. Is `size()` returning the correct value?

Answer (score 1):

The code you've shown is correct (although it could be simpler). I can think of two possible reasons for it to throw an `IndexOutOfBoundsException`:

1. The index passed to `get` is wrong,
2. The method `size()` doesn't return the correct value.

I think it's all we can tell from reading your question.